# How can I tell if a VSTO Add-in is loaded?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

I'm working on a VSTO add-in for Outlook that, if another custom VSTO is loaded, will perform a specific action.  How would I determine if that VSTO is loaded?  I've not delved too far into COM as of yet other than writing a number of add-ins.

Comment: I'm not 100% confident, but I _believe_ it involves accessing [`Application.ComAddIns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.infopath.application.comaddins.aspx) and testing if it exists.

Comment: let me check and i'll get back to you.  thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the key:

"HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins[YourAddInName]"

in the registry.

Existence of the key means that the AddIn is installed.
You can also read the value LoadBehaviour under the above key, the value 3 means that the addin is loaded/to be loaded normally. The value 2 means that the addin has problems.